# How to allow xlsm file type media uploads in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, mime-types, xlsm

Here is my code that I have placed in the functions.php file, which doesn't work:
"Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons." What am I doing wrong?

```
function zerodropout_mime_types( $mime_types ) {
    $mime_types['xlsm'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12';
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'zerodropout_mime_types', 1, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

WP Upload section is designed for media files. That's why your code would work for some custom media file type, but not for XLS.
To enable any kind of file you need to disable default upload type limitation by adding this to your wp-config.php

```
define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
```

After that your code will work.

Comment: Thanks Elvin. This code allows the xls upload and my code is not needed. Is there a way to limit this to Administrators only?

Comment: That's not easy thing. But you can try this code inside some 'init' hook.(or admin_init): 
global $wp_roles;$wp_roles->remove_cap( 'editor', 'unfiltered_upload' );

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
function custom_mime_types( $mime_types ) {
    $mime_types['xlsm'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'custom_mime_types', 1, 1 );
```